# Bash: Comparing names using xargs and if statement

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a folder were if .wav files are uploaded. A progress is triggered to convert the file. This has to be done recursively.

I use inotifywait to start the process if a file is added or changed, Then I want to compare the file extension using an if statement.

However, rather than comparing the value of {} it tries to call a function with the name of the string replaced by {}. This is probably an issue of my if condition.

My pipeline is here:

```
inotifywait -mrq -e create -e moved_to --format '%f' ./ | xargs -I {} bash -c "if '{}' =~ *.wav ; then echo {}  ; fi"
```

How should I compare the extension of the string stored in {}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two main problems are

- You forgot the braces. `if` itself can only check the exit status of the following command and `somefile =~ *.wav` is generally not a command, but `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` is.
- `=~` uses extended regexes which are a bit different from globs. To match all files ending in literally `.wav` you have to write `.*\.wav$`.

```
inotifywait -mrq -e create -e moved_to --format '%f' ./ |
xargs -I {} bash -c "if [[ '{}' =~ .*\.wav$ ]]; then echo {}; fi"
```

However this command might only work for simple file names without special symbols. For instance, it breaks if there is a single `'` inside the file name. It would be safer to write

```
... | xargs -I {} bash -c 'if [[ "$1" =~ .*\.wav$ ]]; then printf %s\\n "$1"; fi' -- {}
```

You could also use the simple and faster alternative

```
... | grep -E '\.wav$'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intention is to filter by certain extension, take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/how-to-use-inotifywait-to-watch-a-directory-for-creation-of-files-of-a-specific

Of if you have more complicated logic to handle different file extensions, you can write your code as

```sh
inotifywait -mrq -e create -e moved_to --format '%f' ./ | while read line; do
    fullname=$(basename -- $line)
    extension=${fullname##*.}
    filename=${fullname%.*}
    echo "fullname=$fullname"
    echo "filename=$filename"
    echo "extension=$extension"
    # now you can do more things with either $filename or $extension
    if [ "$extension" == "wav" ]; then
        echo "to process $fullname"
    fi
done
```